# How to extract values which is match some conditions from list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a new user of Python. And I want to extract specific values from list. My example is here which extract values except for -1. What is a smart way to realize this process?

```
a = [-1, 0, 2,-1, 30]
# new_a = ?? # extract values except for -1
-> new_a = [0, 2, 30]
```

Comment: I found new_a = filter(lambda elm: elm!=-1,a ) is good.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = [-1, 0, 2,-1, 30]
>>> new_a=list(filter(lambda x:x!=-1, a))
>>> print(new_a)
[0, 2, 30]
```

or

```
>>> new_a=[i for i in a if i!=-1]
>>> print(new_a)
[0, 2, 30]
```

or the old school way with an `if` inside `for`

```
>>> new_a=[]
>>> for i in a:
...     if i!=-1:
...         new_a+=[i]
... 
>>> print(new_a)
[0, 2, 30]
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that new_a = filter(lambda elm: elm!=-1,a ) looks also appropriate. Are there any differences to your first example?

Comment: @jef between all the 3 approaches efficiency wise a few milliseconds might differ, but essentially all 3 approaches perform the same thing. Kindly accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark and get the question solved :)

Answer (score -2):

```
In [74]: a = [-1, 0, 2,-1, 30]

In [75]: list(set(a)-set([-1]))
Out[75]: [0, 2, 30]
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for `a = [-1, 0, 2,-1, 2, 0, 30]`.